# Issue in Xcode Error cannot invoke with an argument list of type ‘@value?. @lvalue string!)'

Tags: ios, xcode

cannot invoke with an argument list of type ‘@value?. @lvalue string!)'

So i can this problem when I'm coding, my first app.

(this won't change to a code cause of -catAge.text

Heres my Code

```
@IBOutlet weak var catAge: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var message: UILabel!

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

message.text-catAge.text 

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you intended `message.text = catAge.text`?